# Identify and click button in unordered list if condition met

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using `Python/Selenium` to access an `unordered` list on a webpage. I've used the `find_element_by_xpath` to correctly identify the div I'm after (`text "$x.xx"` will almost always be unique).

I would then like to instruct the code to press the purchase button that resides in the div I've identified (given there are 100 other "purchase" buttons on the same list).

There is one condition however, in the two examples below, one of the `'a classes' includes the text  "disabled".` If the div with the correct text has been identified, but the `'a class' includes "disabled"`, I would like the script to loop and run again 1 second later.

In summary, if I was searching for $50.00 below the code would loop, if I was searching for $30.00 it would click() the "purchase" button in that particular div.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

(apologies if the below isn't formatted correctly, first time posting!)

Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe"
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    
findClick = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='$30.00']")
```

Webpage:

```
 <ul>

    <li class="List-row">
         <div class="List-rowContent Market">
              <div class="Market-item Total"><span>$50.00</span></div>
              <div class="Market-item Buy">
                    <a class="Button-small Market-Buy disabled" data-dialog="#buy_start">Purchase</a></div></div></li>
    
    <li class="List-row">
         <div class="List-rowContent Market">
              <div class="Market-item Total"><span>$30.00</span></div>
              <div class="Market-item Buy">
                   <a class="Button-small Market-Buy" data-dialog="#buy_start">Purchase</a></div></div></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `HTML` that you've shared, the below `xpath`

```
//span[text()='$30.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Purchase']
```

represent `Purchase` button based on price text, you can change this to `50$` and check in `HTMLDOM` .

Now coming to this **question** :

> There is one condition however, in the two examples below, one of the
> 'a classes' includes the text "disabled". If the div with the correct
> text has been identified, but the 'a class' includes "disabled", I
> would like the script to loop and run again 1 second later.

If I understood it correctly, the the below code should work.

```
try:
    if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$30.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Purchase']")) > 0:
        print("$30.00 is visible so bot should click it directly")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='$30.00']/../following-sibling::div/a[text()='Purchase']"))).click()
    else:
        print("$30.00 was not visible so loop it here")
        for i in range(100):
            print("Inside else for loop for the nth time", i)
            time.sleep(20) # for each iteration wait for 20 secs
            #code logic here 
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Perfect, tysm! At the risk of sounding incredibly stupid, the below section: "for i in range(some range here): # do some stuff"..... Is the range the number of list items I am telling it to run through, i.e. (100) will go through 100 <li>..... Is it also possible to declare a parent div class as a range?.....Then the #do some stuff, is that where I write a loop? This is actually the first script I've ever written so by any chance could you provide a basic example so I can play around with it? Again, thanks for your time and patience

Comment: I do not understand this part `Is it also possible to declare a parent div class as a range` range expect integer value, you can use find_elements (plural) and len on top of it to make it return int value,  just like I have done it above.

Comment: Ok great thanks, and sorry for the confusion. So in essence, if I set the range integer to 100, does that mean it loops 100 times? And is it looping every 20 seconds, and it will loop according to what I instruct in the #do some stuff section?

Comment: See above I have updated the code above.

Comment: Thanks so much. Works perfect

Comment: Ok one issue,...Just realised I need to add an 'and' statement in the first part of the code.. Given the three possible outcomes, $30.00 isn't found, $30.00 is found but link not clickable, $30.00 is found and link clickable. The first outcome would return print("30.00 not found"), the second scenario would loop until that link becomes clickable print("waiting for link"), and the 3rd both conditions are met and the click triggered print("success").. Is there an "is clickable" function that returns true/false and I can link with an 'and' statement to the first search for $30.00?

Comment: No, there `isn't` any `built in function`, but you can try to `click` in `loop`, and `assert` the changes when actual `click` occurs.  and based on assert if it fails then retry clicking it is passes then we are good to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237294/discussion-between-user1345331-and-cruisepandey).